# Sub-busca com SQL

Tags: sql

Estou tentando resolver um exercício no khanacademy no curso de SQL e estou com uma certa dificuldade.

O exercicio pede o seguinte:

> Para terminar de criar a lista de reprodução "Pop", adicione outra busca que vai selecionar o título, title, de todas as músicas dos artistas do gênero "Pop". Ela deve usar IN em uma sub-busca aninhada com base em sua busca anterior.

Eu tentei de diversas maneiras e não consegui, notei que se eu usar;

```
SELECT title FROM songs WHERE genre...
```

O sistema já acusa que não existe coluna genre na tabela songs (o que está correto) então como eu poderia buscar por uma coluna em outra tabela se a tabela em que estou fazendo a pesquisa não tem o mesmo nome?

abaixo segue uma imagem do exercicio para que me entendam melhor.

[image: Exercicio KhanAcademy de Sub-busca]

Comment: Tenha em conta que o campo em comum, aquela que existe nas duas tabelas é o nome do artista.(artists.name e songs.artist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Para esta situação é bem simples de se fazer.
Você deve ver quais colunas entre as duas tabelas tem uma ligação (FOREIGN KEY), no seu caso, provavelmente são as colunas "name" da tabela artist e "artist" da tabela songs.
Após ter essa informação em mãos é simples, crie a query que vai retornar os titulos da tabela artists, depois crie uma clausura WHERE onde a coluna "name" da tabela artists pertence (IN) a coluna "artist" da tabela songs, para isso, crie uma query que retorne o artist da tabela de songs onde genre é igual a "Pop".

Segue exemplo:

```
SELECT title
  FROM artists
 WHERE name IN ( SELECT artist
                   FROM songs
                  WHERE genre = 'Pop' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade você seleciona o titulo dos artista onde tem o gênero pop, name é igual a artist então só fiz repetir:

```
SELECT title FROM songs WHERE artist IN ( SELECT name FROM artists WHERE genre IN ("Pop"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT title 
FROM songs 
WHERE artist IN (SELECT name FROM artists WHERE genre = "Pop");
```

Answer (score 1):

> **explicación:**
> es una consulta que implica consultar datos de dos tablas por ende, es necesario hacer un join..

**respuesta:**

```
select title from songs where artist=(select  artist from songs
    inner join artists on songs.id=artists.id
        where artists.genre IN ("Pop"));
```

**Esta consulta la puedes encontrar en khan academy:**
https://es.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/sql/more-advanced-sql-queries/p/challenge-playlist-maker.